# android make user set a date

Tags: android

I want to allow user to set date for something, i wonder if there is a build in for that ? or if there is any example , i am sure that this thing has been used a lot so i just want to know how to make a screen with months and years and days and the user set on date ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DatePicker or TimePicker
Here there is official doc:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html